# Helper doesn't display image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an helper like :

```
def services_display(service)
  if @sleep.services.present?
    image_tag(service.icon, :class=>"icon")
    service.name
  else
    image_tag(service.icon, :class=>"icon-2")
    service.name
  end
end
```

service.name is beign displayed but  no image_tag. What's wrong in my code?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper methods return the value returned by the last line you execute, it does not output the code to the view.

You have to return whatever you wan't to be on the view.

```
def services_display(service)
  if @sleep.services.present?
    image_tag(service.icon, :class=>"icon") + service.name
  else
    image_tag(service.icon, :class=>"icon-2") + service.name
  end
end
```

Your original method is only returning the value of `service.name` and not the string generated by the `image_tag` helper.

Comment: Yes ;) Thanks for your help ;)